# Matlab multidimentional interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I am attempting to visualize a multi-dimensional problem in 2D.
I have a 500x21 matrix of which the first 6 columns are the outputs of an unknown function and the next 15 columns are the inputs, with values between -0.05 and 0.05.
I want to visualize one of the outputs over one of the inputs, while holding the other inputs at a constant value.

My approach is using `interpn` with my matrix and a new matrix called `new_inputs`, which holds the constant values in its columns 8 to 21. Column 7 holds values between -0.05 and 0.05, over which I want to plot column 1 from my original matrix.

```
clc
X_1 =  Matrix(:,7);
X_2 =  Matrix(:,8);
X_3 =  Matrix(:,9);
X_4 =  Matrix(:,10);
X_5 =  Matrix(:,11);
X_6 =  Matrix(:,12);
X_7 =  Matrix(:,13);
X_8 =  Matrix(:,14);
X_9 =  Matrix(:,15);
X_10 = Matrix(:,16);
X_11 = Matrix(:,17);
X_12 = Matrix(:,18);
X_13 = Matrix(:,19);
X_14 = Matrix(:,20);
X_15 = Matrix(:,21);
V = Matrix(:,1);
Xq_1 =  new_inputs(:,7);
Xq_2 =  new_inputs(:,8);
Xq_3 =  new_inputs(:,9);
Xq_4 =  new_inputs(:,10);
Xq_5 =  new_inputs(:,11);
Xq_6 =  new_inputs(:,12);
Xq_7 =  new_inputs(:,13);
Xq_8 =  new_inputs(:,14);
Xq_9 =  new_inputs(:,15);
Xq_10 = new_inputs(:,16);
Xq_11 = new_inputs(:,17);
Xq_12 = new_inputs(:,18);
Xq_13 = new_inputs(:,19);
Xq_14 = new_inputs(:,20);
Xq_15 = new_inputs(:,21);
Vq = interpn(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5,X_6,X_7,X_8,X_9,X_10,X_11,X_12,X_13,X_14,X_15,V,Xq_1,Xq_2,Xq_3,Xq_4,Xq_5,Xq_6,Xq_7,Xq_8,Xq_9,Xq_10,Xq_11,Xq_12,Xq_13,Xq_14,Xq_15,  'linear');
```

However I get this Error:

> Error using griddedInterpolant
> Interpolation requires at least two sample points for each grid dimension.
>
> Error in interpn (line 149)
> F = griddedInterpolant(X, V, method,extrap);
>
> Error in Versuch (line 35)
> Vq = interpn(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5,X_6,X_7,X_8,X_9,X_10,X_11,X_12,X_13,X_14,X_15,V,Xq_1,Xq_2,Xq_3,Xq_4,Xq_5,Xq_6,Xq_7,Xq_8,Xq_9,Xq_10,Xq_11,Xq_12,Xq_13,Xq_14,Xq_15,  'makima');

Can anyone help me identify the issue or does somebody have a better idea how to visualize a multi-dimensional problem in 2D?

Comment: “I want to visualize one of the outputs over one of the inputs, while holding the other inputs at a constant value.” Sounds like you turn it into a 1D problem. I’m not sure though about the difficulty. Are the 15 dimensions sampled randomly or in a grid? In the latter case `interpn` would be appropriate, but I assume creating a 15D grid is just not feasible. So you probably have random sampling (non-grid sampling), in which case you need to use `griddata` for interpolation (`griddatan` for the nD case).